# Firebase displayName return null at first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

- I have object userInfo having field displayName (line17) but userInfo.displayName was null ?? (line18)
- Reload page will solve the problem (have value) (maybe because dependencies are location and navigate)
- I think maybe because I get data while Firebase have't updated displayName yet
- Anyone having solution? Thanks alot

---

I am using firebase for register. But Firebase **only allowed signup with email and password** (not including displayName) so I have to **update displayName manually**

Auth Provider.jsx

```
function AuthProvider({children}) {
const [user, setUser] = React.useState({})
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();

React.useEffect(() => {
    const unSubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth,  (userInfo) => {
        if(userInfo) {
            console.log(userInfo); // line 17 => have value
            console.log(userInfo.displayName); // line 18 => null
            const { displayName, email, photoURL, uid } = userInfo;
            setUser({ displayName, email, photoURL, uid })
            if(location.pathname !== "/profile") navigate("/chat-room")
            return;
        }

        // reset user info
        setUser({});
        navigate("/home")

    })
    
    return () => {
        unSubscribe()
    }
    
},[navigate, location.pathname, ])
console.log(user)
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{user}}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
);
```

Handle Signup.jsx

```
const onFinish = async (values) => {
if (mode === "sign-up") {
  try {
    console.log(values)
    const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      values.email,
      values.password
    );
    await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { 
      displayName: values.displayName,
    })
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You make two separate calls to the Firebase API:

1. First you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to create the user profile,
2. Then you call `updateProfile` to set the display name of the user.

The first call creates the user profile and signs them in, so that call triggers `onAuthStateChanged`. And since the second call hasn't happened yet, your handler will indeed see the user profile without a display name at that point.

As you can see from reloading the page, the display name will eventually show up. Similarly, it'll also show up after up to an hour, when Firebase automatically refreshes the profile. Another option is to call `getAuth().currentUser.reload()` after setting the display profile, which will also force the profile to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

When we call `updateProfile` function and it update `displayName`, `onAuthStateChanged` doesn't triggered. The solution is you have to set user after updateding `displayName` manually `with a different object`.

```
const { user } = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  auth,
  values.email,
  values.password
);
await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { 
  displayName: values.displayName,
}) 

// update `user` state
 setUser({...user});
```

Now the problem should be solved.